# Problem installing RPLidar library

Tags: library

I'm trying to add the [RPLidar library](https://github.com/robopeak/rplidar_arduino/tree/master). I've already checked [this solution](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/rplidar-and-teensy-3-2-need-help-w-library/594525), but it's not working for me, I get this error :

`Error: 13 INTERNAL: Library install failed: extracting archive: Not a supported archive`

Do you have a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to install this library through the Arduino IDE? Then maybe it doesn't work, because this library doesn't conform to the normal library structure for Arduino.

You can install it manually.

- Download the library from Github

  - either by downloading the ZIP-file and extracting it
  - or by using `git clone` on your machine, if you have git installed.
- Move the folder `RPLidarDriver` into the libraries folder. You can normally find this in `Arduino/libraries` in your home directory. If you cannot find it, look in the Arduino IDE in the preferences dialog. There the sketchbook location should be mentioned. `libraries` is a folder inside the sketchbook location.

Then you should be able to compile your code. I've tested this with the examples provided by the library.